# Configuration variable being picked up as method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails when setting a configuration variable in config/application.rb `config.items_per_page = 15` and trying to output it to a controller, I'm getting an error:

```
undefined method `items_per_page'
```

Here's my app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:

```
@posts = Post.where(:is_deleted => 0, :is_hidden => 0).limit(Rails.configuration.items_per_page).order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding the config variable?

Comment: @ZachKemp that fixed it! Feel free to add that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @ZachKemp's recommendation, restarting the rails server resolved this issue.